# Installing Python Package Based on OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, package-managers

For my `environment.yml` file I have a list of dependencies.  One package is only available on `Windows` based systems, but it needed for the package when in that environment.  The other packages can be installed on any OS.

How do I create an environment.yml so that it will only install the package on windows OS?

Current `environment.yml`

```
name: python_dev_env
channels:
- defaults
- anaconda
- conda-forge
- dhirschfeld
dependencies:
- pandas >=0.23
- pip
- python >=3.6
- nbconvert
- beautifulsoup4
- requests
- requests-kerberos==0.11.0
- requests-toolbelt
- requests_ntlm
- requests-oauthlib
- requests-negotiate-sspi
- jupyterlab
- pytest
- matplotlib
- scikit-learn
- scikit-image
- keras
- pip:
  - unittest-xml-reporting
  - setuptools >=38.6
  - sphinx-rtd-theme
```

The package `requests-negotiate-sspi` is the windows only package.

Comment: You will have to create several environment.yml files, there isn't a way to do this that I know of. There are a few other similar questions on here, and the answer has been to make several files. You could up just the file that's different into its own file and use `conda env update` only on Windows though

Answer (score 1):

In the environment.yml file, suffix windows only dependencies with the following

`; sys_platform == 'win32'`

like so

`- requests-negotiate-sspi; sys_platform == 'win32'`

like wise you can mark linux only dependencies with

`; sys_platform == 'linux'`